# The data obtained by WinHttpGetProxyForUrl is always null

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, winhttp, pac

I have the following code:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0A00
#endif

#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        std::wcerr << L"Parameters: <Domain>" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Get proxy settings
    WINHTTP_CURRENT_USER_IE_PROXY_CONFIG ProxyConfig;
    ZeroMemory(&ProxyConfig, sizeof(ProxyConfig));
    if (!WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser(&ProxyConfig)) {
        std::wcerr << L"WinHttpGetIEProxyConfigForCurrentUser failed, error: "
            << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    if (ProxyConfig.lpszProxy != NULL) {
        // Check bypass list
        if (ProxyConfig.lpszProxyBypass != NULL) {
            wchar_t* domain = wcstok(ProxyConfig.lpszProxyBypass, L";");

            while (domain != NULL) {
                if (wcscmp(domain, argv[1]) == 0) {
                    std::wcout << L"Proxy Bypass" << std::endl;
                    GlobalFree(ProxyConfig.lpszProxy);
                    GlobalFree(ProxyConfig.lpszProxyBypass);
                    return 0;
                }

                domain = wcstok(NULL, L";");
            }

            GlobalFree(ProxyConfig.lpszProxyBypass);
        }

        std::wcout << L"Proxy: " << ProxyConfig.lpszProxy << std::endl;
        GlobalFree(ProxyConfig.lpszProxy);
        return 0;
    }

    // Set AUTOPROXY options
    WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_OPTIONS AutoProxyOptions;
    ZeroMemory(&AutoProxyOptions, sizeof(AutoProxyOptions));
    if (ProxyConfig.fAutoDetect) {
        AutoProxyOptions.dwFlags = WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_AUTO_DETECT;
        AutoProxyOptions.dwAutoDetectFlags =
            WINHTTP_AUTO_DETECT_TYPE_DHCP | WINHTTP_AUTO_DETECT_TYPE_DNS_A;
    }
    if (ProxyConfig.lpszAutoConfigUrl != NULL) {
        AutoProxyOptions.dwFlags |= WINHTTP_AUTOPROXY_CONFIG_URL;
        AutoProxyOptions.lpszAutoConfigUrl = ProxyConfig.lpszAutoConfigUrl;

    }
    if (AutoProxyOptions.dwFlags == NULL) {
        std::wcout << L"No Proxy" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    AutoProxyOptions.fAutoLogonIfChallenged = TRUE;

    // Create WinHTTP session
    HINTERNET hSession = WinHttpOpen(
        L"Windows",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS,
        0
    );
    if (hSession == NULL) {
        std::wcerr << L"WinHttpOpen failed, error: "
            << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // Get proxy info from PAC
    std::wstring wurl = L"http://" + (std::wstring)argv[1] + L"/";
    WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO ProxyInfo;
    ZeroMemory(&ProxyInfo, sizeof(ProxyInfo));
    if (!WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(
        hSession,
        wurl.c_str(),
        &AutoProxyOptions,
        &ProxyInfo
    )) {
        std::wcerr << L"WinHttpGetProxyForUrl failed, error: "
            << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
        return 1;
    }

    // ProxyInfo.lpszProxy contains the address of the proxy server
    if (ProxyInfo.lpszProxy != NULL) {
        std::wcout << L"Proxy: " << ProxyInfo.lpszProxy << std::endl;
        GlobalFree(ProxyInfo.lpszProxy);
    } else {
        std::wcout << L"Proxy: NULL" << std::endl;
    }

    // Cleanup
    if (ProxyConfig.lpszAutoConfigUrl != NULL) {
        GlobalFree(ProxyConfig.lpszAutoConfigUrl);
    }

    WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

    return 0;
}
```

It uses the `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl` function to retrieve the proxy server address specified in the PAC file based on system settings.

The `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl` function executed successfully without returning an error, but the given `ProxyInfo.lpszProxy` variable value is always null.

The following is the content of the original PAC file I used:

```
var pHost = "Proxy.local";
var pPort = "1080";
var Socks5 = "SOCKS5 " + pHost + ":" + pPort + "; ";
var Socks = "SOCKS " + pHost + ":" + pPort + "; ";
var Direct = "DIRECT; ";

function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
        if (shExpMatch(dnsResolveEx(host), "*.*.*.*")) {
                return Socks5 + Socks + Direct;
        } else {
                return Direct;
        }
}
```

The following is a simplified version of the PAC file that always returns a proxy server:

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
    return "SOCKS Proxy.local:1080";
}
```

I have tried both, but the `ProxyInfo.lpszProxy` variable still gets null.

Is there an issue with my code or is the `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl` function exhibiting unexpected behavior?

Comment: Are you hosting the PAC file on a web server? Or using the `ftp://` ,`file://` protocol for a PAC file?

Comment: If it is, please show me how to host the PAC file on a web server. If that can be confirmed, I'll report it as an internal issue.

Comment: @Torrecto-MSFT Yes, I host this PAC file through HTTP. As I said, it did not return an error. If I did not use HTTP, then it should return an `ERROR_WINHTTP_UNRECOGNIZED_SCHEME` error.

Comment: I don't know how to describe it. Simply put, I wrote a PAC server program to host PAC files through HTTP and set the correct `application/x-ns-proxy-autoconfig` mime. However, in fact, the way I use PAC files works normally in the system without any problems, and I only encounter problems when using this function.

Comment: Right now i want to reproduce the issue. But I am not familiar with hosting the PAC file on a web server. That's the point. Maybe you should show the steps to how to host the PAC file on a web server. Also, i am doing researching on it at same time.

Comment: https://github.com/fxzxmic/HTTPServerforSingleFile
This is the program I am using, it requires administrator privileges to run.
https://github.com/fxzxmic/HTTPServerforSingleFile/blob/ac037f70c5e69661c62b5e31eb210a27fb96c087/HTTPServerforSingleFile.cpp#L433
You need to change this line to the correct mime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error result is that the `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl` function only recognizes "PROXY" and does not recognize "SOCKS" or "SOCKS5". If you observe the content of the PAC file I mentioned in the question, you will find that I am using either "SOCKS" or "SOCKS5" instead of "PROXY", and these two are ignored by the `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl` function, which is why I always got NULL.

This is an undocumented and unexpected behavior. For the unexpected behavior I mentioned, on the one hand, it refers to the behavior that was not described in the document, and on the other hand, I believe that ignoring "SOCKS" and "SOCKS5" does not match the results I expected after the function is executed.

Anyway, thank him @Torrecto-MSFT for inspiring me to find the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've already reproduced your issue.
The reason you get NULL of ProxyInfo.lpszProxy is that you set wrong address of lpcwszUrl in WinHttpGetProxyForUrl function.

[image]

You should set it to the address of the target that is being proxied.  instead of a server proxy address. **Then the output pointer is not NULL.**

[image]

In my pac file, I used localhost:8000  to  proxy baidu.com.

```
function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {
 if (shExpMatch(url, "*baidu.com*")){
    return "PROXY localhost:8000; DIRECT";
 }else{
    return "DIRECT";
 }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not. My code and usage of this function are correct, the error is that the `WinHttpGetProxyForUrl` function only recognizes "PROXY" and ignores "SOCKS5" and "SOCKS". You can try it out.

Comment: This is an undocumented and unexpected behavior. Anyway, thank you for inspiring me to find the real problem.

Comment: @Fxzxmic Aha, that may be out of my knowledge. Also, can you explained what kind of  unexpected behavior. Is that mainly on WinHttpGetProxyForUrl  or SOCKS5? You can make an answer for guidance!!

Comment: I don't know what happened, but I vote up for you.

Comment: *"I don't think there's anything wrong with my answer."* - It meaningfully changed the problem by randomly adding a port to the domain. It is now an answer to a different question. *"At least it works confirmed by OP as inspiration."* - Stack Overflow is not a forum. It's a Q&A site. If you post an answer, it necessarily must address the question being asked. This is not the case here.